# Error while installing release version of Flutter app on Android 12 : "Parse Error : There was a problem parsing the package"

Tags: android, flutter, parsing, installation, apk

I have a Flutter app, working properly on multiple Android and iOS devices.
Recently I found it's release version APK can't be installed on Pixel phone having Android 12, I receive this error :

**Parse Error : There was a problem parsing the package**

(I am using Flutter 2.5.3, current latest version)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Android 12 and later any launchable activity should contain this flag in manifest :

```
exported="true"
```

Comment: This answer helped me, I have also referenced the following link for more detail explanation https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/fixing-there-was-a-problem-while-parsing-the-package-on-android-12-d62365d5a8b

Comment: how can we apply exported attribute to flutter plugins?

Comment: Thanks so much, this help me as well.

Comment: Also, please check Merged Manifest section and update your error dependencies with latest android 12 supported versions.

Comment: Not work for me please review and help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502338/parsing-the-package-issue-in-react-native

Answer (score 15):

use

```
android:exported="true"
```

on activity
follow the image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

please install android SDK 30 in android studio

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've already installed SDK 30, but will try SDK 31 today and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using razorpay in your project then you will have to add these lines in your manifest-

```
  <receiver
            android:name="com.razorpay.RzpTokenReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rzp.device_token.share" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/CheckoutTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <data
                    android:host="rzp.io"
                    android:scheme="io.rzp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Avebrahimi said (Try him first)

> In Android 12 and later any launchable activity should contain this
> flag in manifest :

```
android:exported="true"
```

### Didnt work?

But, still in many cases it doesn't works. So if it doesn't works, try to **sign your app** with a `custom key`, instead of default `test key`. It worked for me